# AddEventListener() javascript snake game. move without input?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function loop() {
  MainBoard.moveSnake(); // moves the snake in the array
  MainBoard.checkFood(); // checks for food and grows if there
  MainBoard.drawSnake(); // refreshs canvas and draws updated snake
}

function main() {

  MainBoard = new GameBoard();
  MainBoard.generateFood();
  MainBoard.drawSnake();

  window.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    if (event.defaultPrevented) {
      return; // Do nothing if the event was already processed
    }

    switch (event.key) {
      case "ArrowDown":
        // code for "down arrow" key press.
        if (MainBoard.direction == 'N') {

        } else {
          MainBoard.direction = 'S';
          MainBoard.loop();
        }
        break;
      case "ArrowUp":
        // code for "up arrow" key press.
        if (MainBoard.direction == 'S') {

        } else {
          MainBoard.direction = 'N';
          MainBoard.loop();
        }
        break;
      case "ArrowLeft":
        // code for "left arrow" key press.
        if (MainBoard.direction == 'E') {

        } else {
          MainBoard.direction = 'W';
          MainBoard.loop();
        }
        break;

      case "ArrowRight":
        // code for "right arrow" key press.
        if (MainBoard.direction == 'W') {

        } else {
          MainBoard.direction = 'E';
          MainBoard.loop();

        }

        break;


      default:
        return; // Quit when this doesn't handle the key event.
    }
    loop();
    // Cancel the default action to avoid it being handled twice
    event.preventDefault();
  }, true);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>

</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Snake.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Snake_Board.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="type/css" href="exit_button.css">

<body>

  <h1 header="Snake" id="Snake">Snake</h1>
  <p intro="Intro">Eat the food (Using the arrow keys) and don't hit your tail/go out of bounds!</p>
  <canvas id="Board" name="Board"></canvas>

  <!--<input type = "button" onclick = "main()" value = "Play">  -->

  <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="SnakeScript.js"></script>-->

  <script src="SnakeScript.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    main()
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Hi guys, I am writing a basic snake game into a webpage. I have it working and moving correctly; however, I can only figure out how to move it when a key is pressed. I want the snake to move independently every .75 seconds and have the user choose the direction. If the user didn't press anything it would move anyways with the default or current direction. I'm confused on how to do this with addEventListener(). It seems that it is always in the addEventListener() and never leaves it? Anyone have any hints? anything helps. Thanks!

Comment: You can use `setInterval()` to run a function periodically.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want to execute code with an interval.

```
setInterval(yourfunction, 3000);
```

Basically, create a variable that stores your direction, and with the interval, move the snake. There are a lot of great videos on YouTube of programming this game to check as well for some extra help.

**Check out:**

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Answer (score 0):

Have the snake move on its own by constantly calling your `MainBoard.loop()` every 0.75 seconds using a `setInterval(MainBoard.loop, 750);`. Do so by taking it out of your `addEventListener`. Then to your `window.addEventListener` have it only change the direction and nothing else.

Comment: thank you! I tried that before and it didn't work. it's working now!